# Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided> but Context was expected

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment

I inform you, this by making an application and I try to verify if it has permissions to save files this from a fragment but it is giving me an error in the declaration of the context (this) with the error message of Type mismatch: inferred type is  but Context was expected.

Any help is appreciated from the heart

My code

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        downloadButton.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {

            // here I would like to move to FormActivity
            override fun onClick(v: View?) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                            100
                        )

                    } else {
                        saveImageToStore()
                    }
                } else {
                    saveImageToStore()
                }
            }

        })
    }

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                saveImageToStore()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "ASDASDA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace:

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)`
by

```
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(),android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

and

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
    this, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),100)
```

by

```
 ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        requireActivity(), arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),100)
```

`ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission()` requires Context reference as first parameter and you are passing a Fragment reference by using 'this'

`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` requires an activity reference as first parameter and you are passing a Fragment reference by using 'this' as well

You should give a try to the new way to request permissions at runtime by using `registerForActivityResult(RequestPermission())`
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#request-permission

Comment: Could you mark the answer as accepted, please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `requireContext()` instead of `this`. A Fragment is not a Context. You need to use `requireContext()` instead of just `context` because `context` is a nullable `Context?`. It's safe to use the non-nullable `requireContext()` in the `onActivityCreated()` function.